# Making React Router resilient to application errors

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Hi have a web app that uses [React Router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router) and `<Link />` tags for navigation.  However, my app is fairly complex and occasionally a javascript error occurs (despite my best efforts!)

The result for users in this case is the app becomes unresponsive.  Specifically `<Link />` tags do not respond.  This is much worse than a standard server side app, which typically still allow anchor tags to work. 
 The only solution for React-Router is to refresh the page using a browser command.

In this case, I would like for React Router to still be able to navigate using hrefs as backup, or something else.

Is there a way to make react-router navigation more resilient to application errors so that users can continue to navigate `<Link />`s?